# How to sort replies by date - latest reply show first

Tags: php, codeigniter

first i want to apologize for my bad english, but i want to ask:

I have a ticketing system and i want to sort my replies by latest reply. Now the sorting is from oldest and now i want to sort by newest

I am using CodeIgniter as framework, and Perfex CRM as script

That's a part of my code, i don't know what can i do for sorting>

```
   <div class="panel-footer">
   <?php echo _l('ticket_posted',_dt($ticket->date)); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php foreach($ticket_replies as $reply){ ?>
   <div class="panel_s">
      <div class="panel-body <?php if($reply['admin'] == NULL){echo 'client-reply';} ?>">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 border-right ticket-submitter-info">
               <p>
                  <?php if($reply['admin'] == NULL || $reply['admin'] == 0){ ?>
                     <?php if($reply['userid'] != 0){ ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo admin_url('clients/client/'.$reply['userid'].'?contactid='.$reply['contactid']); ?>"><?php echo $reply['submitter']; ?></a>
                     <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php echo $reply['submitter']; ?>
                        <br />
                        <a href="mailto:<?php echo $reply['reply_email']; ?>"><?php echo $reply['reply_email']; ?></a>
                     <?php } ?>
                  <?php }  else { ?>
                     <a href="<?php echo admin_url('profile/'.$reply['admin']); ?>"><?php echo $reply['submitter']; ?></a>
                  <?php } ?>
               </p>
               <p class="text-muted">
                  <?php if($reply['admin'] !== NULL || $reply['admin'] != 0){
                     echo _l('ticket_staff_string');
                  } else {
                     if($reply['userid'] != 0){
                      echo _l('ticket_client_string');
                   }
                }
                ?>
             </p>
             <hr />
             <a href="<?php echo admin_url('tickets/delete_ticket_reply/'.$ticket->ticketid .'/'.$reply['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger pull-left _delete mright5 btn-xs"><?php echo _l('delete_ticket_reply'); ?></a>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <?php if(has_permission('tasks','','create')){ ?>
               <a href="#" class="pull-left btn btn-default mtop5 btn-xs" onclick="convert_ticket_to_task(<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>,'reply'); return false;"><?php echo _l('convert_to_task'); ?>
            </a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
         <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
               <?php if(!empty($reply['message'])) { ?>
                  <a href="#" onclick="print_ticket_message(<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>, 'reply'); return false;" class="mright5"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
               <?php } ?>
               <a href="#" onclick="edit_ticket_message(<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>,'reply'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
         <div data-reply-id="<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>" class="tc-content">
            <?php echo check_for_links($reply['message']); ?>
         </div>
         <?php if(count($reply['attachments']) > 0){
            echo '<hr />';
            foreach($reply['attachments'] as $attachment){
             $path = get_upload_path_by_type('ticket').$ticket->ticketid.'/'.$attachment['file_name'];
             $is_image = is_image($path);

             if($is_image){
              echo '<div class="preview_image">';
           }
           ?>
           <a href="<?php echo site_url('download/file/ticket/'. $attachment['id']); ?>" class="display-block mbot5"<?php if($is_image){ ?> data-lightbox="attachment-reply-<?php echo $reply['id']; ?>" <?php } ?>>
            <i class="<?php echo get_mime_class($attachment['filetype']); ?>"></i> <?php echo $attachment['file_name']; ?>
            <?php if($is_image){ ?>
               <img class="mtop5" src="<?php echo site_url('download/preview_image?path='.protected_file_url_by_path($path).'&type='.$attachment['filetype']); ?>">
            <?php } ?>
         </a>
         <?php if($is_image){
            echo '</div>';
         }
         if(is_admin() || (!is_admin() && get_option('allow_non_admin_staff_to_delete_ticket_attachments') == '1')){
            echo '<a href="'.admin_url('tickets/delete_attachment/'.$attachment['id']).'" class="text-danger _delete">'._l('delete').'</a>';
         }
         echo '<hr />';
      }
   } ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
   <span><?php echo _l('ticket_posted',_dt($reply['date'])); ?></span>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="btn-bottom-pusher"></div>
<?php if(count($ticket_replies) > 1){ ?>
   <a href="#top" id="toplink">↑</a>
   <a href="#bot" id="botlink">↓</a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ORDER BY Date DESC` or `ORDER BY Date ASC` ? see : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results

Answer (score 0):

In the 5th line of this snippet

```
<?php foreach($ticket_replies as $reply)
```

$ticket_replies is the result of some query (which is not pasted here). Also from this line

```
<span><?php echo _l('ticket_posted',_dt($reply['date'])); ?></span>
```

it can be seen that there is a 'date' column. As already mentioned in the comment above add 'ascending' or 'descending' order by clause to the query.